# Keyboard shortcut to open the first option in a search in mozilla firefox

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, firefox

In mozilla firefox, after i have entered a search string and searched for it, is there any keyboard shortcut which can let me directly open the first or second option (perhaps in a different tab)? I understand that pressing the tab button till it reaches the desired location is an option, but that i find a bit cumbersome. Any help?

Comment: Can you explain - search entered where?

Comment: Perhaps an example might help bring more clarity. Let's say I google for "cheese", and it gives me a whole lot of options. Now, what I want is a wiki article on 'cheese', which happens to be my first option in the search results. My question is, is there any way I can get to that article without dabbing on the tab button multiple times or without using the mouse?

Comment: But it sounds like "vendor lock".. I mean google is not the only one search engine and another search engines can have a different links layout.

Comment: I tried various Google searches and the number of times one has to press *Tab* varies so I don't think what you want is possible. If was always a fixed number a solution using a script based on *xdotool* would be possible.

Comment: Thanks @DKBose. In the absence of any other solution, this seems like to be one of the possible way out. Would be glad if you could put it as a answer (the deleted comment was quite helpful, would appreciate that in the answer too), so that it might help similar lost souls in some different time. A hat tip to S_Flash for his (her?) interest in this matter.